# JSONP CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: json, cors

There are many questions about CORS policy in JSON. But I did not find any solution which does not need a server side change. I have no access to the server.

My code is:

```
$.getJSON('https://app-prod-ws.meteoswiss-app.ch/v1/forecast?plz=800000&callback=?', function(data){});
```

Is there any client only workaround?

Comment: BTW, a simple Google search for "CORS error workaround" reveals this article: https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The above solutions seemed too complicated to me. I found an easier one via php. I am not sure if this works in all cases but it does for mine.

```
<?php
   $meteoschweizData = file_get_contents("https://app-prod-ws.meteoswiss-app.ch/v1/forecast?plz=800000");
   echo "const meteoschweizJSON = '" . $meteoschweizData . "';";
?>

const meteoschweizData = JSON.parse(meteoschweizJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the purpose of CORS is to prevent a Website from accessing data it's not supposed to see. For example, a malicious Website shouldn't see anything from Facebook.

Having said that, there are a few options:

1. The client can use a CORS extension to bypass CORS protection.
2. You can use a CORS proxy (not recommended)
3. You can have your server request the resource on the server side and return it to the Web browser.

Comment: How would I setup a CORS proxy?

Comment: @Reto You wouldn't necessarily set one up. Just google "cors proxy"